# upgrading ACF (advanced custom fields) on an old site

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, upgrade

I have a site that needs to be updated and it was running an old version of ACF (4.4.1).  I had to get a new version of ACF because we don't ahve a good copy of the old.  So when i updated my image fields stopped working.  I think there is likely a code change that happened, but i don't know.

Can someone please help me upgrade this code so it will work with ACF 5.3.7?

```
<?php
if (get_field('slideshow')) :

  $repeater = get_field('slideshow');

  foreach( $repeater as $key => $row ) {
    $column_id[ $key ] = $key;
  }

  array_multisort( $column_id, SORT_ASC, $repeater );

  foreach( $repeater as $i => $row ) {
    $size = get_field('slideshow_size') ?: 'Panoramic';
    $column_id[ $i ] = $row['slideshow-image']['id'];
    $showcontrols = $active ? true: null;
    $active = (!$active) ? ' active' : ' ' ;

    $controls[$i] = '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="'.$active.'"></li>';
    $image = $repeater[$i]['slideshow-image']['sizes'][$size];
    $imgs[$i] = '<div class="item'.$active.'"><div style="overflow:hidden;border-radius:5px;border: 1px solid #987d2b;"><img src="'.$image.'"></div></div>';
  }
?>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php if($showcontrols): foreach ($controls as $control) { echo $control; } endif; ?>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php foreach ($imgs as $img) { echo $img; } ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($showcontrols): ?>
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the wordpress backend I see that the field groups shows that the image in the OLD ACF returns image object, but now it's returning an image array.

the slideshow function is working on both sites but on the new is just returning "" as the image url when it is loaded on the front end.

Comment: why do people vote this down?

Comment: I do not know what you expect when asking an off topic question. Please see [ask] and [help] and understand that specific support for third party plugins are off topic here. You should be contacting the ACF support group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code to one of my sites to test with ACF version 5.3.9.2.
And it works for me I just had to make sure the field name and image size were correct.

```
$size = get_field('slideshow_size') ?: 'Panoramic'; // Make sure this size exists, and usually is all lower case.

$column_id[ $i ] = $row['slideshow-image']['id']; // Field names in ACF normally have an under score _ not a dash -

$image = $repeater[$i]['slideshow_image']['sizes'][$size]; // Same here
```

So just check those three things and I believe that should be it!

Comment: thanks for the help.  the code doesn't work.  I think you've definitely put me on the right track.  I didn't write the code, and agree with your underscore/hyphen statement.  The code does work on the old site though.  When i change the $size to 'large' images load so it's something to do with that for sure.  i'll keep testing.